# User story for drag and drop feature

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop, requirements, user-stories

Can anyone help me create a User Story for the dragging and dropping feature, where I can drag and drop projects from "New Project" to "In progress" etc Column

Comment: Hi -- it would help us for you to show us what you know, what you have tried and then ask a specific question.  Unfortunately, this isn't a programming question -- so it might be closed as off topic.  If you ask elsewhere, you should try to write the story as best you can and ask for advice/help on making it better

Comment: Maybe this will help you get started: https://www.atlassian.com/agile/project-management/user-stories

Comment: I actually want to know the acceptance criteria for dragging and dropping projects across different column

Answer (score 1):

[User-stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story) describes a feature from the user's point of view, making clear what the user wants to achieve.  We cannot invent stories for your users: normally, you should discuss this with your users.  But if you're learning and it could help, here an hypothetical example:

> **As a** *project manager* **I can** *drag a project icon in the "new project" column across my kanban board and drop it on the "in progress" column*, **so that** *I can easily and intuitively communicate that a project was started and is still going on.*

Be aware that referring explicitly to a drag and drop seems very detailed and might not leave much room to propose better solutions. In this regard, you need to keep in mind that a story is not a detailed specification.  It's just [a placeholder for a conversation](https://www.agilealliance.org/user-story-conversations/).  Personally, I'd rather go for something simpler like:

> **As a** *project manager* **I can** *easily chose a project to launch and show that it is currently in-progress*, **so that** *the other users know on which project they may work.*

I would then discuss with the user about the details of the story.  Maybe drag and drop is the way to go. Maybe keyboard control (tab to select, space to chose target) is needed for **[accessibility reasons](https://www.w3.org/blog/wai-components-gallery/widget/accessible-drag-and-drop/)**.  But perhaps I'll discover that some users prefer to update the status in the project card if it's on the screen.

Anyhow, during this conversation [you'd write down all the expectations, positive and negative, for the acceptance criteria](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories).  For example:

- Dragging from "new" and dropping on "new" cancels the drag&drop operation
- When dragging from "new" a visual feedback should be given to show the project moving
- During the dragging,  the use of the escape button may cancel the operation.
- When the project is dropped by accident,  the user may undo the operation.
- When the project is successfully dropped on the "in progress" column,  any open view of the project card should be immediately opened to show the new status of the project.
- Attempting to drag a project, of which the user is not responsible, should lead to an error message about missing authorisations, etc.. .